# LCD screen is not working properly

Tags: windows, lcd

I have a Compaq Presario CQ40-337TU laptop with a 250GB harddisk and 2GB of RAM. I have Windows 7 32 bit. My laptop's screen becomes very blurry or vague sometimes after starting. This vagueness prevails and then it goes off automatically. Sometimes when I restart the laptop after observing the blurry screen, the very first screen — "Press esc key to..." — becomes yellowish. Is it a hardware problem? Or a software problem? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call that one a hardware issue. It could be anything from a loose flex that connects the LCD to the mainboard to a faulty component within the LCD itself. In any case, these aren't really issues you can fix yourself easily or without voiding your warranty. If I were you, my first step would be a call to Samsung's warranty section.

Comment: actually my warranty doesn't exist now.in this case if i contact the compaq service center should they replace the total LCD(actually it would cost a lot) or this problem can  be solved by troubleshooting my current lcd????  do this type of problem in the LCD increases if i continue to use the laptop?????

Comment: They would probably replace the whole LCD assembly. If your warranty is in fact expired it would probably be at cost, as you said. It might be possible for you to do the replacement yourself - try googling "cq40-337tu replace LCD." Oh, and if my answer helped, please do me a favor and check that checkmark next to the answer - thanks!